# Assign values to multiple edit boxes, given their names

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

i am currently doing some programming in Borland C++ Builder 6.

I have 24 edit boxes(a visual component, with a text field) and i want to insert some values in the boxes, now i do it like this:

```
Edit1->Text=1;
Edit2->Text=2;
Edit3->Text=3;
...
Edit24->Text=24;
```

but i want to have something like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<25;i++){
Edit"i"->Text=i;
}
```

i think i have to make an array of objects or something.
Can any body help me with this? I don't have a lot of experience with objects and stuff like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `FindComponent` function in VCL. It is used to find a component by it's name.

In your case it will look something like:

```
TEdit * tmp;
for( int i = 0; i < 24; i ++ )
{
    tmp = (TEdit*)MyForm->FindComponent("Edit" + IntToStr(i) );
    tmp->Text = i;
}
```

Comment: just tested it, worked great! this is gonna save me lots of lines of codes! thanks!